# Whenever I render, the cube appears over the model but everything looks fine on the view port render

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

The cube appears in if I render the model[image]

Comment: what is that cube? something is not good in your settings, maybe take a look at the Outliner, is the eye icon enabled for the cube?

Comment: For reference: https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/

Answer (score 1):

Welcome here!
Whenever you need help and post in any kind of website, it would be nice from you to provide more info about what you did, what you expected, what actually happened, what you tried to solve the problem, give [screenshots](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/) to illustrate all of that, and indicate what software you're using (and its version) as well as your operating system. It will make everything easier and faster, both for us and you.

My first guess is that you disabled the visibility of your cube in the viewport, but not in the render.

Chac your outliner, you might have something like this :

[image]

Eye icon is for Viewport visibility, Cursor icon is for selectability, Camera icon is for renderability. The simplest way to not have your cube in the render is to uncheck the camera icon.

If this doesn't solve your issue, you will have to do what I said above: give more infos.